# Weakly convergent distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ with densities relating to Lebesgue-measure that do not converge

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

> > Show that there exist weakly convergent distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ that have a density relating to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ but the densities do not converge. Hint: $f_n(x):=1+\cos(2\pi n x)$

To be honest I do not understand this task completely.
Nevertheless I tried to use the given hint. Maybe
$$
\nu_n(x):=f_n(x)\lambda(x)
$$
are those distributions on $\mathbb{R}$? At least $\nu_n\ll\lambda$ and both $\lambda$ and $\nu_n$ are $\sigma$-finite so that from Radon-Nikodým it follows that there is $\lambda$-a.s. a density of $\nu_n$ relating to $\lambda$. But I do not know if this is meant and especially if the $\nu_n$ do weakly converge...

Could you please help me?

Sincerely yours

math12

Comment: Did youbtry to draw graphs of the proposed densities?

Comment: Yes, I did. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Your measures $\nu_n$ define distributions by the rule

$$\nu_n(g)=\int_\mathbb{R} g(x) d\nu_n(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x)g(x) d\lambda(x)$$

for $g\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Now your job is to notice that the $\nu_n$ converge distributionally, i.e. there is a distribution $\nu$ s.t.

$$\nu_n(g)\rightarrow \nu(g)$$

for all test functions $g$, but on the other hand, the sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ does not converge (say, pointwise).

**Hint:** Use the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: In our lecture, weakly convergent means that for all bounded continious functions $g$ it is $\lim_{n}\int g\, d\nu_n=\int g\, d\nu$. So now I have to find $\nu$?

Comment: This doesn't make a difference. Yes, that is what you have to do.

Comment: Do you mean with your hint to use that $\lim_{\lvert t\rvert\to\infty}\int e^{itx}\, d\nu_n(x)=0$?

Comment: Yes, in particular $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} \cos(2\pi n x) g(x) d\lambda(x) = 0$...

Comment: Sorry, I do not see, why from $\lim_{\lvert t\rvert\to\infty}\int e^{itx}\, d\nu_n=0$ it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(2\pi n x) g(x)\, d\lambda(x)=0$ resp. is then $v=0$ the searched measure?

Comment: My problem is: Isn't it the aim to know that $\int (1+\cos(2\pi nx))g(x)\, d\lambda(x)\to 0, n\to\infty$?

Comment: No, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} (1+\cos(2\pi nx)) g(x) d\lambda(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) d\lambda(x)$, so $\nu=\lambda$ is your answer.

Comment: Thank you now I got it!! You made my day, thank you!

Comment: @math12: Glad I could help :).

Comment: And $(f_n)$ isn't convergent, because $\cos(2\pi nx)$ does not converge, right?

Comment: @math12 Exactly

Comment: Ok, now the task is finished for me. Again many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, there is one point I did not understand completely, have to ask again, sorry: Why is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\cos(2\pi nx)g(x)\, d\lambda(x)=0$?

Comment: This is the content of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. Proof: assume wlog. $g$ is smooth (smooth functions are dense), integrate by parts (integrating $\cos(..)$ and deriving $g$), this gives a factor $1/n$, that shows convergence to $0$